# Ant pass specific string values from one file to another

Tags: regex, ant, filter

I'm trying to configure autoincrement of version number in an Android aplication.
I've configured Ant tasks which make a checkout of the file then autoincrement the string with version value and then automatically do check-in in TFS system. So this test.properties file has this contetnt:

```
versionCode="1"
```

Autoincrement did this task:

```
<propertyfile file="${basedir}/src/test.properties">
  <entry key="versionCode" value="1" type="int" operation="+" />
</propertyfile>
```

How would I configure replacement of the value of this string: android:versionCode="1", located in the target file androidmanifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use the [`ReplaceRegExp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) in Ant:

> Directory-based task for replacing the occurrence of a given regular expression with a substitution pattern in a file or set of files.

It might look something like this:

```
<replaceregexp file="${src}/androidmanifest.xml"
           match="android:versionCode=&quot;[0-9]+&quot;"
           replace="android:versionCode=&quot;${versionCode}&quot;"
/>
```

The `build.number` property could be obtained by reading in the property file before running this task.

Comment: I got incremented version only one time, after that the values have been changing only in my build_info.properties. This is content of build_info.properties: build.major.number=02
build.revision.number=06
build.minor.number=00

Answer (score 0):

A solution with vanilla ant, no Ant addon needed, you may use a propertyfiletemplate that has =

```
f.e. named props.txt
    ...
    android:versionCode=@versionCode@
    ...
```

and later on use the property ${versionCode} set by your workflow
and create a propertyfile from your template with copy + nested filterset =

```
 <!-- somewhere set in your workflow maybe via userproperty -DversionCode=42 -->
  <property name="versionCode" value="42"/>
 ...
  <copy file="props.txt" todir="/some/path" overwrite="true">
   <filterset>
    <filter token="versionCode" value="${versionCode}"/>
   </filterset>
  </copy>
```

/some/path/props.txt will have =

```
...
android:versionCode=42
...
```

see [Ant Manual on filtersets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html)

Comment: Thanks it works for me . I've just changed values here  match="android:versionCode=&quot;[0-9]+&quot;" set to  match="android:versionCode=&quot;(.*)&quot;"